# Android: Safe and secure place in internal storage to backup my app data

Tags: android

I want to backup my app data. **I have tried Android's `BackupAgent`,** but it seems to be quite unstable and does not work for some devices.

So, I would like to instead backup my app data to internal storage. Thus, I require a safe location where I can backup my data.

Note: I would not like to backup data to external storage since the SD might not always be available.

I would like some suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing my local backup using:

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "Android" +
                File.separator + "data" + File.separator + ".backup" + File.separator`

I had to change the folder name since,

> Android deletes the respective package from /Android/data/ when the app is uninstalled

Moreover, I prepend the folder name with a `.` so that it remains hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Since Android 6 there is a Backup API. See http://developer.android.com/training/backup/autosyncapi.html

Comment: Thanks @barq. I am aware of that. But my app targets pre Marshmallow devices also. There is a Backup API which needs to be implemented for this case. As mentioned in my question, that is quite unreliable. Hence I need to backup to internal storage.